# jquery calling a function

Tags: jquery, json, get

yet again thanks for looking.

i like to call a function (eg. comment_disp, post_disp or any other i create later on).

i have created a json function with url, fname and id can i use fname as a function name?

```
// on document ready runs
json('comments.php','comment_disp');
```

- url = url to get
- fname =  function
- name  id = post or any other data id.

> ```
> json = function(url,fname,id){
> $.getJSON(url,(fname));
> }
>
> comment_disp = function(json){
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript. You can put them into parameters directly, no need to transport their name as string.

So instead of

```
json = function(url,fname,id){ $.getJSON(url,(fname)); }
```

do

```
json = function(url,f,id){ $.getJSON(url, f); }
```

and call it as

```
json('comments.php', comment_disp);
```

Comment: @Gumbo: I wanted to make clear that the function *itself*, not its *name* should be transported. The argument name of course makes no difference, it could (though logically wrong) be kept as `fname`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your functions are available in the "global scope" (i.e. not written as a private member of another class/constructor), you can call your functions by string name like this:

```
window['comment_disp']();
```

This would be the equivalent of calling

```
comment_disp();
```